# Paste an Excel range in browser using Selenium + VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario where I am trying to copy a range of cells (Single Column) from Excel and paste the range in a textarea tag in Chrome browser, which is identified using ID. I am using Excel VBA and Selenium.

There seems to be no error when copying of the range. However, when I try to paste the range in the textarea using Selenium Keys, I am currently unable to paste the values. As my Excel range can sometimes extend to more than 1000 rows, I am out of option to paste the cells one after the other, as the browser times out.

My html code is something like this.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
<div>
    <div>
        <textarea> id = "textarea1"
        </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

I have tried using the below three codes, in vain.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
selenium.findElementByID("textarea1").sendkeys (keys.Control & "v")
selenium.findElementByID("textarea1").sendkeys keys.Control, "v"
selenium.findElementByID("textarea1").sendkeys (keys.Control +"v")
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Can someone help me identify the issue here and the workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what keybindings you're using for Selenium (Python or Java?).

Anyway, you want to send a key chord. Please look at the examples in [Key press in (Ctrl+A) Selenium WebDriver](https://web.archive.org/web/20171004183440/http://seleniumwebdrivertrainings.com/key-press-in-ctrla-selenium-webdriver/).

So maybe you want:

```
selenium.findElementByID("textarea1").sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"v"))
```

Comment: I am not sure of the keybindings you are talking about. Hope this helps. This is how I am calling the key bindings.    =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Dim keys As New SeleniumWrapper.keys

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: Okay I see you are using the VBA keybindings. I misunderstood your background info. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449770/selenium-vba-to-control-chrome and see that they use `driver.SendKeys Keys.Control, "t"`